# Caching most of Symfony components and services

Tags: php, symfony, caching, memcached

Having a Java background, one point I have missed during many years is that PHP recreates everything at every request.

So using the Symfony framework, we recreate every components of this - yet great - framework. Every service, all the router, are built and rebuilt.

We can cache data in `$_SESSION`, but we save 50 times data if we have 50 users. I thought I could use `static` or `$_SERVER`, but it doesn't work the Java way.

The PHP way is to use **Memcached** and there are plenty of exemples caching the doctrine requests, but I haven't seen any of them caching the Router or the Services. Do you know exemples, or is it just a bad idea ?

Comment: I think this might be a rather extreme example of premature optimization.  Take the time to research and understand what memcache really is as well as how sessions, static functions and even $_SERVER actually works.  You might be surprised.  Better yet, build an app or two.

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the characteristics of PHP, nothing lives once the request is finished.

There're a couple of projects where they wrap the bootstrapping process of symfony so it's only run once. Here's the project: [php-pm](https://github.com/php-pm/php-pm) and an article describing it's [usage](http://marcjschmidt.de/blog/2014/02/08/php-high-performance.html)